# Azure Synapse - How to catch SparkException

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, azure-synapse

I tried below things:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkException
from org.apache.spark.SparkException import SparkException
from org.apache.spark import SparkException
```

These all give **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'org.apache.spark.SparkException'**.

I need to handle PySpark exceptions in Azure Synapse like below:

```
except (Py4JJavaError, SparkException, TypeError) as e:
   print(e)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`org.apache.spark.SparkException` is the scala exception thrown in JVM process, you can't and don't need to handle this in pyspark

Comment: why one don't need to do it? how can one recover from an error without catching the exception?

Answer (score 0):

Since Spark 3.5 we can import it from `pyspark.errors.PySparkException` - [source](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.errors.PySparkException.html).

In previous versions you will have to use the general broad Exception class. But if you are expecting the exception within Pytest, you can also do the following:

```
with pytest.raises(Exception, match="SparkException"):
    df.collect()
```